# azure active directory app registration shows wrong publisherDomain

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a multi-tenant (i.e. any O365 tenant) app registered in the AAD V2 app registration portal.

After registering the app I have changed the primary custom domain in the corresponding aad.

In the admin consent screen the wrong custom domain is displayed.

In the manifest it also shows the incorrect publisherDomain. The publisherDomain setting cannot be changed by editing the manifest.

The app name, logo, terms link, privacy link can all be changed as expected.

If I register a new test app the publisherDomain in the manifest is correct.

The app is in production with several clients using it. I don't want to have to delete and recreate the app registration to resolve this.

Comment: I assume you registered it by logging in with your AAD account to the v2 portal? Kinda sounds to me like a support request is needed. Upvoted for awareness though, members of the team check here daily.

Comment: Yes. I have an O365 tenant myself and that is where the app is registered and where the custom domains are.

Answer (score 0):

> After registering the app I have changed the primary custom domain in
>   the corresponding aad.

When you register an application using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/, the application will be registered in the home tenant of the account that you use to sign into the portal. If you explicitly wish to register an application in a particular tenant, sign in with an account originally created in that tenant.

After the app registered, property `publisherDomain` is read-only and cannot be set.

[image]

Comment: As I said above, this is a multi-tenant app and you can't change the publisherDomain via the manifest since it is read only. There should be a huge warning about the domain since it can never be changed after the app is registered.